# How to access JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

How will I access this data in javascript?

```
[
    {
        "itemData": [
            {
                "Key": "218",
                "Value": "اسلامشهر"
            },
            {
                "Key": "219",
                "Value": " بهارستان"
            },
            {
                "Key": "220",
                "Value": " پاكدشت"
            },
            {
                "Key": "221",
                "Value": " پرديس"
            },
            {
                "Key": "222",
                "Value": " پيشوا"
            },
            {
                "Key": "223",
                "Value": " تهران"
            },
            {
                "Key": "224",
                "Value": " دماوند"
            },
            {
                "Key": "225",
                "Value": " رباط كريم"
            },
            {
                "Key": "226",
                "Value": " ري"
            },
            {
                "Key": "227",
                "Value": " شميرانات"
            },
            {
                "Key": "228",
                "Value": " شهريار"
            },
            {
                "Key": "229",
                "Value": " فيروز كوه"
            },
            {
                "Key": "230",
                "Value": " قدس"
            },
            {
                "Key": "231",
                "Value": " قرچك"
            },
            {
                "Key": "232",
                "Value": " ملارد"
            },
            {
                "Key": "233",
                "Value": " ورامين"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I used AJAX in JSON format.
I tried access JSON like:

```
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data.d[0].itemData, function (index, element) {
        alert( data.d[0].itemData[index].key);
    })
}
```

but not getting output.

Comment: Can you post the *actual* JSON being returned, not the visualisation of it in the console. It will make it much clearer to navigate.

Comment: Try this instead: `data['d']['0']['itemData']`

Comment: Have you tried to parse it first? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

So json parse data and then console.log(it).

Comment: @DanielPanic jQuery will already do that for you. Also, if the console is showing it in that format it has already been converted to an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `d` property in your JSON, so you can simply access `data[0].itemData`. Try this:

```
$.each(data[0].itemData, function (index, element) {
    console.log(element.Key);
})
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ve8jky61/)